# How to find inverse matrix over modulo three field?

Tags: proof-verification, inverse, matrix-calculus

Find the inverse matrix of the following matrix, $$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&1\\1&0&1\\1&1&0\end{bmatrix}$$ over $F_3$, i.e., all elements are one of $\{0, 1, 2\}$.

---

I first found its determinant. (I found it using first row as coefficients.)

\begin{align}
\det A &= 0 \cdot \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}
- 1 \cdot \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}
+ 1 \cdot \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\\
&= 1 + 1 \\ &= 2.
\end{align}

Then, the inverse of $A$ is

\begin{align}
A^{-1} &= \frac{1}{\det A}
\begin{bmatrix}
+\left|\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\1&0\end{array}\right| &
-\left|\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\1&0\end{array}\right| &
+\left|\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\1&1\end{array}\right|\\
-\left|\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\1&0\end{array}\right| &
+\left|\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\1&0\end{array}\right| &
-\left|\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\1&1\end{array}\right|\\
+\left|\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\0&1\end{array}\right| &
-\left|\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\1&1\end{array}\right| &
+\left|\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\1&0\end{array}\right|
\end{bmatrix}\\
&= \frac12 \begin{bmatrix}2&1&1\\1&2&1\\1&1&2\end{bmatrix}\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}1&0.5&0.5\\0.5&1&0.5\\0.5&0.5&1\end{bmatrix},
\end{align}
where $\left|M\right|$ represents determinent of M.

The problem is that $0.5$ is not a member of $F_3$.

In this case, is the answer $!\exists ~ A^{-1}$ ? or is my solution process wrong?

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: 2*2 = 4 = 1 (mod 3). halving is the opposite of multiplying with 2. so try replacing 0.5 with 2s and verify.

Comment: The inverse of $2$ in $\mathbb{F}_3$ is 2 itself

Comment: Oh my god!! Thank you so much, I got it....